# Question marked as duplicates should have links to the duplicates

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions

So many times across the Stack Exchange sites do I come across the questions marked as duplicate. But I won't find the answers for the question because it is a duplicate of some question that I don't know the whereabouts of.

So my point is that there should be clear links to those possible duplicate questions.

Comment: Could you link to a question where that is not the case? There's always a link. (Some very old questions might have issues, but they are rare.)

Comment: @Mat I dont have any of them at hand, However I had these problems before and I came across the `META` site. I just thought maybe it would help. Anyway if what you say works for 90% of the time then no issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is already the case for any question that gets closed now. It shows the duplicate at the top of the question.

In the old days, the question body was changed to show the duplicate question. It is possible it was edited out some time. You should still see the duplicate question mentioned in the post history. Those questions are quite rare now. I have actually seen just a few cases over the years on SO.